# What determines response time of hyperlinks - conventional install, @USB and 'portableapp.com' versus NETWORK/ISP response time?

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome, usb, opera

Trying '@USB' and 'portableapps.com' installation of browsers - Chrome, Firefox, Opera and I am getting some inconsistent, irregular response times, or apparent response times for these browsers installed on 32 GB Sandisk USB drives?

Most familiar with Opera which I can tweak a bit by running Opera Turbo, but what suggestions are there for telling what delays are this side of the NIC and those delays from the ISP on the other side of my NICs?

Pragmatically I look for how soon hyperlinks are active on a page, using Process Explorer and a screen capture utility for making 'snapshots'when I seem to encounter delays and so far these delays, lagging response times, and even complete internet feed dropout always seem to occur south, or on the network side of the system NIC.  My ISP providers technicians can't agree amongst themselves - four visits and I've gotten four different 'word pictures' of the situation - if I can collect data and graphics to prove my point, why can't I get them to provide the data, specs, and graphs supporting their claims of bandwidth, no dropouts or fallouts of Internet signal, and so on.

Also I have no information on the ISP's bandwidth assignment or bw algorithm -- one tech said the TV audio/video signal gets 'first dibs' after that Internet, and if anything is left over, for VOIP?  Surely that data must be generated on an almost continuous basis somewhere by a systems monitoring/function no?

Another suggestion was made that on applications running on USB thumb drive as 'stand alone' versions, whether @USB or 'portableapps.com' versions, the 'pseudo' system support must be generated intrinsically, on the USB drive, by the stand-alone application, or by the support mileau as in 'portableapps.com' that to the extent a 'distant USB app' doesn't get resources locally, then it has to search the system, e.g. for Java, or Adobe Acrobat, JS or JavaScript, MS or QT media player, and so on.  It all sounds logical and practical, but I cannot find any sources to read in support of this 'theory' - where to go to read, how to find reading resources?  Clearly some of it must be basic USB main PC interaction with the USB or 'portapps" standalone applications as the next layer of elaboration?

Dont want to make this a computer science engineering or Consumer Reports laboratory testing project, what are suggested as some quick n dirty, if valid, things to measure?

BTW this project has two goals: to reduce the size and functional load of all business traditionally conducted by \WINDOWS... and \Program Files\ all restricted to and eating up primary HDD -- aside: has anybody matched the growth, over time, of applications, as the amount of primary HDD space has increased?  Its my impression code is flabbier, not as compact and expands to use the available "surplus" space on larger and larger HDD and now SDDs?